# javascript- assign text file data to array

Tags: javascript

I have a text file newfile.txt  like this:

```
aa, 78
bb, 78.98
cc, 567
dd, 987
```

I need it to be read by JavaScript and assigned to GLOBAL variables

```
<script>
// the magic javascript to convert the txt to: 

$aa = 78;
$bb = 78.98;
$cc = 567;

function anything(){
// be able to use $aa here
            }
<script>
```

If that gone be complicated, I can make my txt file like this, one column:

```
98
45.98
45
23
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't possible without using an array of some kind

Comment: What specifically are you having problems with? Parse the text file? Create global variables? Where does the text file come from? How are you trying to read it?

Comment: can you transform your text file into json format? `{'aa': 78, 'bb': 78.98, ...}`

Comment: thank you all for your comments, i was so confused, i think i confused you all!

Comment: thank you all for your comments, i was so confused, i think i confused you all!  the dats is stored in remote mysql server, i used php to pull the data and save it in newfile.txt , now the data could be just one colomn in the txt file, and i need a javascript to read the file and asign each number to a variable so i can do calculation with them, please ignore the aa, 78 format, lets say we have one txt file with several numbers in one single column, .. if i could put the in $array then i could use the data like $array[0]  or $array[2]

Comment: this is what i used to generate the txt file   <pre> <code><?php
// connect
$host = "localhost";
  $user = "_draw";
  $pass = "hjjuh@oi";

  $databaseName = "hhjk_draw";
  $tableName = "draw";

  $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
  $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);

$query = "SELECT * FROM draw";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$output = "\r\n";
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $output = $output . $row['nawi_draw'] . ", " . $row['nrx'] . "\r\n";
}
$newfile="newfile.txt"; 
$file = fopen ($newfile, "w"); 
fwrite($file, $output); 
fclose ($file); 
?></pre> </code>

Comment: @ Felix Kling the text files comes from a mysql database, using php saved in the root of my website, if i could load one column (the numbers) into a javascript array my problem would be solved

Comment: @cjds i would be quite happy if i could put one colomn of data into a javascript array, that is all i need, disregards the aa and bb vars, just one array for the digits column will be ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save in an object variable, doing something like:

```
var x = `aa, 78
        bb, 78.98
        cc, 567
        dd, 987`;

var result = x.split(/\n/).map(function(e) { 
    var obj = {}; 
    var spl = e.split(', ');
    obj[spl[0].trim()] = spl[1].trim();
    return obj;
});

//result should be: [{"aa":"78"},{"bb":"78.98"},{"cc":"567"},{"dd":"987"}]
```

Comment: thank you for the coce, is not quite what i wanted, my problem is pulling the data from a txt file and putting it in an Array or single variables so i can do calculation with the data